# ASP.NET iFrame src requires preceding forward slash, hard coded path does not

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When I have an `<iFrame/>` in my razor file with its `src` hardcoded without a preceding slash, the pdf renders fine within the `iFrame`:

```
    <iframe src="UploadedPdfs/analytics.pdf"
            width="800"
            height="800"
            runat="server"
            id="iframepdf">
    </iframe>
```

But if I set up the `src` to be dynamically passed through a property on the model, It only works if I prepend the path with a forward slash:

```
    PdfView pView = (PdfView)ViewData["PdfView"];
    string pRelativePath = pView.relativePath;

    <iframe src=@( "/" + pRelativePath ) //pRelativePath when debugging is equal to UploadedPdfs/analytics.pdf
            width="800"
            height="800"
            runat="server"
            id="iframepdf">
    </iframe>
```

Here is what the html for the above variable passed path, **without a slash** looks like, this **does not render** the pdf:

[image: iFrame inspection]

With the forward slash preceding the variable value, this is the resulting html, which **renders fine**:

[image: iFrame inspection2]

Is this normal / expected?

Comment: What is rendered in the browser in the last example? And what do you expect it to be?

Comment: I expect it to be a pdf, same as in the first bit of code. The path is the same...

Comment: Then the only reason is that the URL should actually start with `/` since it's an absolute path. If you are on say `mysite.com/Home` and requests `UploadedPdfs/analytics.pdf`, the browser will look for `mysite.com/Home/UploadedPdfs/analytics.pdf`, but with the slash in the beginning it will look for `mysite.com/UploadedPdfs/analytics.pdf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some weird quotes in your last bit of code. It should be like:

```
@{
    PdfView pView = (PdfView) ViewData["PdfView"];
    string pRelativePath = pView.relativePath;
}

<iframe src="@pRelativePath"
                width="800"
                height="800"
                runat="server"
                id="iframepdf">
</iframe>
```

That works without a forward slash in the beginning, and renders like your first bit of code:

```
<iframe src="UploadedPdfs/analytics.pdf"
                width="800"
                height="800"
                runat="server"
                id="iframepdf">
</iframe>
```

Comment: the extra quote is my own typo while adding the code on here. And, no, still doesn't work without preceding forward slash...

Comment: I've removed the typo so that its not misleading as the cause of the issue.

Comment: What is it that doesn’t work? Error message, or wrong path rendered? And also, your code doesn’t have quotes around the src attribute.

Comment: The pdf is not being presented by the iFrame. Even without the quotes, it works after adding a preceding forward slash, the pRelativePath variable is a string anyway, so does it need more quotes around it ?

Comment: I have, tried adding quotes around the whole thing, but it only works when the path starts with a forward slash

Comment: Did you try my suggestion, using just ”@pRelativePath” instead of wrapping it with @(...)? It should have qoutes to be valid HTML.

Comment: Hehe, yep I did all that. The reason why I now have this @() is because I am now doing the concatenation within. Otherwise before that I tried everything, @pRelativePath, @(pRelativePath)....

Comment: I however don't remember trying this: `src = "@pRelativePath"`. Let me try it and get back to you. Maybe that's the magical speck

Comment: Can you post the HTML that gets rendered when you try src=”@pRelativePath” as an edit to your post?

Comment: this `src="@pRelativePath"` doesn't do it. I still had to add the slash for it to work: `src="/@pRelativePath"`